# Allocating a Type so it Matches a Variables Type

Tags: typescript

I am making trying to create a small function that will take an array of type apple | orange | pear | mango and convert that to a coresponing custom made Dictionary Interface which is just an object.

My code:

```
  private mapArrayToDictionary = (
    array:
      | Apple[]
      | Orange[]
      | Pear[]
      | Mango[]
  ) => {
    const sorted: Dictionary<typeof array> = {};
    array.map((fruit) => (sorted[fruit.id] = fruit));
    return sorted;
  };
```

I am trying to dynamically allocate the returning array to be of the same type as the array passed in as a parameter. Then I will take that id as the key and the value as the fruit object itself.

I am getting the error "Type 'Apple' is not assignable to type 'Orange[] | Pear[] | Mango[]. etc.

I assume I could make just a generic fruit interface type, but I am not understanding why this "type of array" does not carry over. Thank you

Edit: 
My function that works for all same property fruits

```
function mapArrayToDictionary(
  array:
    | Apple[]
    | Orange[]
    | Mango[]
) {
  type AnyFruitArray =
    | Apple
    | Orange
    | Mango;

  const sorted: Dictionary<AnyFruitArray> = {};
  array.map(item => (sorted[item.id] = item));
  return sorted;
}
```

My interfaces for the fruit:

```
export interface Fruit {
  name: string;
  type: string;
}

export interface Apple extends Fruit{
  id: number;
}

export interface Pear extends Fruit {
    id: number;
    location_id: number;
    location_name: string;
    producer: string;
}
```

How I call the function:

```
const apples = await CalAPI.fetchApplesByIds(fruitIds);
this.setState({ relApples: mapArrayToDictionary(apples)});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to the rescue:

```
private mapArrayToDictionary = <T extends { id: string | number }>(
  array: T[]
) => {
    const sorted: Dictionary<T> = {};
    array.map((fruit) => (sorted[fruit.id] = fruit));
    return sorted;
};
```

Note that `Fruit` doesn't have a property `id` so you won't be able to simply use `<T extends Fruit>`, though if you want to restrict this method to just accept types that also implement the fields of `Fruit`, I'd recommend an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) `<T extends Fruit & { id : string | number }>`.

Alternatively, if there are only a few known fruit types you need to handle (and assuming all of those types contain a valid `id` property), you could make a union of those known fruit types:

```
type KnownFruit = Apple | Orange | Pear | Mango;
...

private mapArrayToDictionary = <T extends KnownFruit>(
  array: T[]
) => {
    const sorted: Dictionary<T> = {};
    array.map((fruit) => (sorted[fruit.id] = fruit));
    return sorted;
};
```

Comment: I cannot get the second solution to work as I get an error "Pear is not assignable to type T". The first solution seems to work fine, but only when all the fruit has the same properties. If Pear has an extra property, then I get an error. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @C.Programming Can you show what `Apple`, `Pear`, etc. actually looks like, an how you're calling this method?

Comment: @C.Programming In your updated question, `Pear` doesn't have a `id` property, so it doesn't satisfy the constraint on `T`. You can either move `id: string` to your base `Fruit` interface or use `name` or `type` for indexing `sorted` rather than `id`.

Comment: I apologize, pear does have an id property

Comment: @C.Programming I understand the problem now. `id` was a number rather than a string. I've updated my answer to reflect the new information.

Comment: I had the id as a number, the problem persists where if I add Pear to my type KnownFruit definition, then I get a cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Which upon investigation, looks like it means that the pear doesn't have the exact same properties as the other fruit. (duck typing)

Comment: @C.Programming It really shouldn't need the *exact* same properties unless somewhere you have `var apple: Apple = pear` or similar. What is `Dictionary<T>` by the way? That's not a built-in type and perhaps it's causing some issues.